# Angular failed to upload file

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

Here is a bunch of my backend code that I have used to upload a file.

```
$app->post('/upload/{studentid}', function(Request $request, Response $response, $args) {

    $uploadedFiles = $request->getUploadedFiles();

    // handle single input with single file upload
    $uploadedFile = $uploadedFiles['filename'];
    if ($uploadedFile->getError() === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {

        $extension = pathinfo($uploadedFile->getClientFilename(), PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        // ubah nama file dengan id buku
        $filename = sprintf('%s.%0.8s', $args["studentid"], $extension);

        $directory = $this->get('settings')['upload_directory'];
        $uploadedFile->moveTo($directory . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename);

        // simpan nama file ke database
        $sql = "UPDATE feepaid SET filename=:filename WHERE studentid=:studentid";
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $params = [
            ":studentid" => $args["studentid"],
            ":filename" => $filename
        ];

        if($stmt->execute($params)){
            // ambil base url dan gabungkan dengan file name untuk membentuk URL file
            $url = $request->getUri()->getBaseUrl()."/Upload/".$filename;
            return $response->withJson(["status" => "success", "data" => $url], 200);
        } else {
            return $response->withJson(["status" => "failed", "data" => "0"], 200);
        } 
    }
});
```

When i tested using postman its working but im quite new to Angular. When i implement the api in my Angular apps its not working

[image]

And this is my code that i use to upload the file from angular application

```
  fileChange(event) {
    const fileList: FileList = event.target.files;
    if (fileList.length > 0) {
      const file: File = fileList[0];
      const formData: FormData = new FormData();
      formData.append('uploadFile', file, file.name);
      const headers = new Headers();
      /** In Angular 5, including the header Content-Type can invalidate your request */
      // headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
      // headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
      const id = sessionStorage.getItem('userId');
      // const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
      this.http.post('http://localhost:8080' + '/upload/' + id , formData)
        .subscribe(
          data => console.log('success'),
          error => console.log(error)
        );
    }

  }
```

And this is my example of testing using Postman

[image]

Why is it i have error? It seems like my file is not send to the backend and its return null value. Anyone can help me? Thank you

Comment: Is that API is working from PostMan or fiddler?

Comment: Its working on PostMan. I didnt test it on fiddler

Comment: Can you show us how you are sending data on the postman(Screen shot)?

Comment: I have already edited my question

Comment: Try: `formData.append('filename', file);`

Comment: It executes without errors, but it did not post it to the database. You have any idea why??

Comment: Not sure why but try with `formData.append('filename', file, file.name);`

Comment: ok nvm i will open a new question. Thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to send the exact key-value pair for Form Data as you retrieve the key as `filename` so try changing:

```
formData.append('filename', file, file.name);
```

Comment: Yeah already done that but it did not insert the file name to database. Any idea why?

Comment: If that is working from postman then the problem is in angular code itself

Comment: i tried console.log(data) but it returns null and yeah must be the angular code. Thank you anyway :)

Comment: Can you change the code from `subscribe` to `Promise`?

Comment: I have worked with FormData but My Backend was Web.API

Comment: Do you mean like this  .toPromise().then(
          data => console.log(data),
          error => console.log(error)
        );"

Comment: I already did that but still return a null value but nvm i think i will reconstruct my code.